# Is there any way to use json objects in SQL

Tags: mysql, json, database-design, architecture

Here's the problem:

We have a MySQL database in which we store JSON strings. Until now this was no problem, but suddenly our client requested we do search/order/other operations with these objects. Since the projects is at a fairly late state, going to Mongo is not a choice the team leader wants to make, so I'm asking is there a quick way to use these JSON strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JSON as intention**

There is no way to work with JSON in MySQL. Some DBMS may support JSON, but that's out of the question, and, besides, any sort of such "support" is only about performing some JSON-specific operations, but not about modelling your architecture (and those two things are completely different) More, in full sense, model concept (i.e. relations) for MySQL is different than JSON is: as a Relational DBMS, it follows [relational data model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database), and JSON is completely different format. You will store it as plain string value, thus, impossible to do anything with it in some other way, if not use string functions. So even working with JSON you will do that not inside relational model, thus, it won't be possible to maintain relational features, such as referential integrity, for instance.

**Options to resolve**

You have several options:

- Migrate to Postgree SQL as it has extended support for json, since version 9.4 it's [jsonb](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html) and it's even faster. This might be the best option since it's RDBMS and therefore the migration won't be that hard like for truly document-oriented DBMS.
- Or migrate to Mongo now (if that's your intention), before it's too late. Take in account, that Mongo is completely different thing than RDBMS, it's document-oriented. I guess this is the best option both for your project and for your client (and your task would be to explain that)
- Change entire architecture so you won't store JSON objects and will work with normalized (in terms of relation DB) entities. This means - yes, entire refactoring of all code, changing all relations etc. In real situation it's just theoretical option, you won't be given neither time nor money for that.
- Implement your own JSON library for MySQL. Is it hard? Depends of what you will do with your JSON, but [JSON](http://json.org/) is public format, so you will know what to do, at least. You may do it either as [UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-udf.html) or at user-land (so with [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-function.html) statement). This will require specific skills and time, of course. The bad things: bugs. Even if you'll be able to create those functions faster than re-structure your architecture or migrate to Mongo, you will never be certain of quality of those functions. There's no way to test that code natively. However, I may give hint for the case of user-land functions - you may use [`mysql-unit`](http://almadomundo.github.io/mysql-unit/) to test your stored code, if your MySQL is 5.6 or higher (well, I've written this tool, but.. it may contain bugs too)

**"Standard" functions**

Finally, if you're running MySQL 5.7, then there may be a ray of hope with [pre-release JSON functions](http://labs.mysql.com/) - so, you may *try* to use alfa-version of JSON functionality, which currently exists for MySQL 5.7. But I would not (strongly) recommend to use that in real project since those functions are neither well-tested nor complete at all. But, to install those function, you'll need to download corresponding package, then plug them into your server, like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION json_append       RETURNS string  SONAME 'libmy_json_udf.so';
CREATE FUNCTION json_valid        RETURNS integer SONAME 'libmy_json_udf.so';
CREATE FUNCTION json_extract      RETURNS string  SONAME 'libmy_json_udf.so';
CREATE FUNCTION json_replace      RETURNS string  SONAME 'libmy_json_udf.so';
CREATE FUNCTION json_remove       RETURNS string  SONAME 'libmy_json_udf.so';
CREATE FUNCTION json_set          RETURNS string  SONAME 'libmy_json_udf.so';
CREATE FUNCTION json_merge        RETURNS string  SONAME 'libmy_json_udf.so';
CREATE FUNCTION json_search       RETURNS string  SONAME 'libmy_json_udf.so';
CREATE FUNCTION json_contains_key RETURNS integer SONAME 'libmy_json_udf.so';
```

And after that you'll be able to try them.

Comment: Well, we'll probably go to Mongo, but you spiked my curiosity to these pre-release JSON functions. Where can I read more about them?

Comment: I've provided a link. They are under development stage (even not beta) - so by definition they can't be documented properly. Try to find more at MySQL Labs - to be honest, I've never used those functions.

Comment: The relational model doesn't prohibit using JSON. In fact, values can be arbitrarily complex. See, for example, Chris Date's book *An Introduction to Database Systems*, 7th ed, p 114.  PostgreSQL supports [JSON](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html).

Comment: And what does it has to do with relational DB concept?Do PostgreSQL has library to work with JSON? Sure,and I didn't say all DBMS are not supporting JSON (as you can see, even for MySQL there's more or less related library). But simply think about what is this kind of support. _Do you really can create a relation `between separate` entities inside JSON entries?_ No. _Do you really can maintain referential integrity with JSON data?_ No. I may continue, but concept was shown: if you can work with JSON structures, it doesn't mean they are aligned with the model itself. But thanks for dv explain.

Comment: The relational model supports data types that are arbitrarily complex. That means it supports XML, video, audio, and JSON, among other things. Of course you can't set a foreign key reference to a field in a JSON value, but that's irrelevant, and shows a fairly deep misunderstanding about what the relational model is about. You can't set a foreign key reference to a field in a date value, either. And there's nothing in the OP's question that suggests he's even *trying* to set a foreign key reference.

Comment: Relational model does not mean only FK integrity - it's much more. Even if OP didn't say that explicitly, entire question is about architecture and data modeling. That means, JSON is no more a string value which may be used in some functions, but it now determines relations, connections etc - so, fundamental structure definer. If not so, no way it was a use-case for Mongo, but it is - and that is why just JSON functions have nothing to do with the question, it's much wider issue.

Comment: I prefer the alfa-romeo-version.

Comment: This is a direction that Oracle is going in for 12c and beyond.  When we start seeing structures of any kind inserted into columns that are treated more than abstract blobs we are getting a little lost. For JSON or any other kind of YAML we can select an manipulate using string functions but ideally we should be lifting things out and replacing them as atomic objects. Otherwise we will end up extending SQL to the point where we photoshop JPG's and transcode video inside embedded SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any MySQL specific functionality, you could switch over relatively painlessly to PostgreSQL, and utilize its JSONB data type.

If you look at the [official wiki page regarding its inclusion in PostgreSQL 9.4](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.4#JSONB_Binary_JSON_storage), then you'll see that with this, you are able to store raw JSON and query against it. As an example, given this JSON structure (I replaced the PostgreSQL-specific column types with standard types, except for the JSONB type:

```
table booksdata ( 
    title text not null,
    isbn text not null primary key,
    pubinfo jsonb not null 
)
```

You can then query against it to find the average cost of all books from a single publisher like this:

```
SELECT avg((pubinfo #>> '{"cost"}')::NUMERIC) 
FROM booksdata
WHERE pubinfo @> '{ "publisher" : "It Books" }';
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL5.7 now supports a JSON data type - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Seems they didn't want to get left out of the NoSQL conversation.

```
mysql> SELECT JSON_ARRAY('a', 1, NOW());
```