# Postgres row_to_json function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json, postgresql

Is there any pretty and neat translation of this Postgres query into a MySQL one? Basically, I want to copy values from table_1 into table_2, but in json format, with table_2 not being in first normal form.

```
INSERT INTO table2(json_meta_data) SELECT row_to_json(row(field_1, field_2)) FROM table_1;
```

PS: I am not sure about the correctness of this query in Postgres, but I googled and found out [Postgres has such functions](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql).

#### Answer for MySQL 5.7+

Check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html

Comment: You may check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154048/is-there-any-way-to-use-json-objects-in-sql/25154323#25154323) - so MySQL can't work for now with json (if only some experimental extension)

Comment: No, MySQL has no (built-in) support for JSON. And the gap will even be bigger once Postgres 9.4 with it's enhanced JSON support is released

Comment: @AlmaDo that's why I wrote: "*built-in*"

Comment: Considering that I only want to generate a json string, I think I can write a function. It maybe generate json string by concat() operation. Since I want it to be general, it should be with variable number of arguments. something like to_json(ke1, value1, key2, value2, ...). Can you help me with it?

Comment: "I think I can write a function"..."Can you help me with it? " hey, either you can or you can't. If it was so easy why isn't it already available in lots of places? ...

Comment: Why so angry @Used_By_Already :P

Comment: angry? confused is more like it. If you commence writing your function I wish you the greatest of success. If you get stuck you may ask questions. I am merely trying to warn you that sometimes what looks easy isn't quite as easy when you get into it.

Comment: Thanks @Used_By_Already. Considering lack of the desired function in MySQL, and after thinking a bit more, I guess the best way for me is to generate the query string in PHP, in which I have more flexibility. However, I am afraid the PHP code will get a bit dirty :(